# Can I make my ASP.NET CalendarExtender larger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, calendarextender

I'm developing a mobile version of my company's website. I don't have an extensive history in ASP.NET programming, but so far most of my work on the project has been HTML manipulation anyway. For the most part, it's been pretty simple to just scale/resize/rearrange all the various text fields and buttons such that they display pretty nicely on a mobile device. One of the text fields, however, has a CalendarExtender attached to it, and the little calendar pop-out is so small it's difficult to even read on a mobile device, to say nothing of trying to actually select a specific date. Is there a simple way I can just make the calendar bigger? It doesn't seem to have any of the typical resizing attributes I've seen (height, width, font-size, etc).

In case it helps, I'm programming on Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010, in C#.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So it's almost more of a hack than a solution, but it works splendidly and doesn't cause any problems for me:

It turns out that the previous programmer who worked on this page had set the objects on the page to be rather large, and then zoomed the page out. Since I couldn't scale the calendar up, I scaled everything else down and changed the zoom attributes of my page to start the user zoomed in enough that the calendar is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 3):

The [calendar extender](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) use the css properties that starts with **ajax__calendar** and you can find them onn StyleSheet.css that come with the [SDK samples](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/). You can change the, and change the view of it. By change that css and include it on your project you can change the way its look.

By adding fonts and font size on the **ajax__calendar_container** you can make it bigger.
I will type them here for help.

```
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_container 
{
    border:1px solid #646464;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    padding:4px;
    margin:4px;
}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_footer {border-top:1px solid #f5f5f5;padding:3px;margin:3px;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_dayname {border-bottom:1px solid #f5f5f5;padding:0;margin:0;}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_day {border:1px solid #ffffff;padding:0;margin:0;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_month {border:1px solid #ffffff;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_year {border:1px solid #ffffff;}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_day {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#0066cc;color:#0066cc;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_month {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#0066cc;color:#0066cc;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_year {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#0066cc;color:#0066cc;}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_day {background-color:#ffffff;border-color:#ffffff;color:#646464;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_year {background-color:#ffffff;border-color:#ffffff;color:#646464;}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#daf2fc;color:#0066cc;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#daf2fc;color:#0066cc;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year {background-color:#edf9ff;border-color:#daf2fc;color:#0066cc;}

.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_title {color:#0066cc;}
.MyPopupCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today {color:#0066cc;}
```

In [this page open the Calendar](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) Theming to view some more details.

Comment: Thanks, I tried editing several of those properties. Some of them don't appear to do anything, but I did manage to make the text bigger for the days. However, the actual size of the buttons didn't change; just the text. So now all of the numbers are overlapping each other, and I haven't been able to discern a way to spread them out (I have tried the padding and margin attributes in several of the ajax__calendar subcategories).